# How to make sqlite accept Arabic?

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to create a data entry program and I have this table called StoringTF
and here's its scheme.

```
CREATE TABLE StoringTF
(Store_code INTEGER,
Store TEXT,
Product_Date TEXT,
Permission INTEGER,
Product_Code INTEGER,
Product_Name TEXT,
Incoming INTEGER,
Unit_Buying_Price INTEGER,
Total_Buying_Price INTEGER,
Outgoing INTEGER,
Unit_Sell_Price INTEGER,
Total_Sell_Price INTEGER,
Description TEXT)
```

I want the Description column to accept Arabic letters. for example, I tried inserting Arabic letters.
But the output was weird symbols and question marks. Is there a way to insert this with Arabic letters or doesn't SQLite support Arabic at all?
Thanks.

Edit: Thank you very much for all contributions. I tried displaying the table and it worked in both Pandas and Excel which means the problem was with the prompt itself not the python or sqlite code. Thanks again.

Comment: you need to encode to utf8 and decode back from utf8 when you retrieve it (It maybe already converting it to utf8 when you store it... but explicit is better than implicit)

Comment: @JoranBeasley   
How can I do that?+ Is it possible when the entry is through tkinter through a GUI so I don't think it's possible especially when I'm using a dictionary that gets direct data from text boxes for entry.Can you please explain in more details how that is done ?

Comment: You really need to show the code you are using to get data into this table. The database is not the problem.